# Powershell: Invoke-RestMethodt delivers an unexpected empty line

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

I am sending a query with `Invoke-WebRequest` and want to output a value from the response header. For this I wrote a function that contains the following query:

```
Invoke-RestMethod @Params -ResponseHeadersVariable ResponseHeader
```

The Result as expected:

```
$ResponseHeader.'OData-EntityId'
```

xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx

However, if I put this logic into a function, I get an additional blank line that interferes with further processing of the value. **How do I get rid of it?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with adding `| Out-Null`

**Invoke-RestMethod @Params -ResponseHeadersVariable ResponseHeader | Out-Null**

Comment: Just as a side note, `$null = Invoke-RestMethod` or `[void](Invoke-RestMethod)` are both more efficient as they do not pass the result through the pipeline to another cmdlet. Using `Out-Null` a lot will slow your functions or script down. Worth noting if performance is a consideration.